# Алгоритм преобразования строки

Tags: c++builder, алгоритм

Как в с++ билдире сделать функцию, которая заменяет прописную букву после точки на заглавную?

пробелы есть, представим что весь текст мы напечтали маленькими буквами, при вызове данной функции все буквы после точки становятся большими...
мне бы исходничек..читала что можно использовать функцию UpperCase ()но не знаю как ею тут воспользоваться

Может мне кто-то пропишет код...Пожалуйста

Comment: Прописная буква и есть заглавная. Если про строчную, то она идёт сразу после точки или есть пробелы после точки, одно вхождение или несколько? И требуется решение для учебной задачи или более реальный пример (во втором случае проще взять регулярные выражения, поскольку условия задачи могут поменяться не раз)

Answer (score 2):

Анализируйте строчку посимвольно. Нашли точку следующий символ пишите большим.

Comment: Не следующий, а после него, т.к. после точки идет пробел, который тоже есть символ.

Comment: Когда я писал ответ, то задание состояло из одной строки 
**сделать функцию, которая заменяет прописную букву после точки на заглавную**

Answer (score -2):

функция замены строчных на заглавные AnsiUpperCase(имя строки);

Comment: Во первых это меняет всю строку на заглавную, Во вторых это Delphi функция и в С++ ее может вполне не быть.

Comment: и правда это из делфи,извиняюсь...